# What Causes Fatal Signal Exception on Rails App Deployed by Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm new to Heroku, and I'm at a loss as to why the SIGTERM is thrown five lines down in a section from my log below.

I've read the other pages on Stack Overflow re this issue, and they didn't seem to help. I'm trying to deploy a Rails app, if that helps.

This has caused https://boiling-mountain-81402.herokuapp.com/ to return an error page.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

```
2017-03-28T20:27:09.062696+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-03-28T20:27:09.063321+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-03-28T20:27:08.911221+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user evilofbanality@gmail.com
2017-03-28T20:26:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-03-28T20:27:10.139053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162238+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-28 20:27:10] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162266+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162268+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in start'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162269+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162270+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162270+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162271+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162271+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162272+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162275+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162275+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162277+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162278+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162377+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-28 20:27:10] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2017-03-28T20:27:10.245251+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2017-03-28T20:27:10.245246+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2017-03-28T20:27:10.162461+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-28 20:27:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2017-03-28T20:27:10.245249+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:20809
2017-03-28T20:27:10.245250+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-03-28T20:27:10.245256+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-03-28T20:27:10.412918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-03-28T20:27:13.753372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 15314 -e production`
2017-03-28T20:27:17.047827+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-28 20:27:17] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2017-03-28T20:27:17.047862+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-28 20:27:17] INFO  ruby 2.2.6 (2016-11-15) [x86_64-linux]
2017-03-28T20:27:17.048080+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-28 20:27:17] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=15314
2017-03-28T20:27:17.188828+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-28T20:27:19.643169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=boiling-mountain-81402.herokuapp.com request_id=170e9b83-3d23-4171-8b98-a27cbd5a45c3 fwd="38.98.150.200" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=62ms status=500 bytes=1754 protocol=https
2017-03-28T20:27:21.232647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-mountain-81402.herokuapp.com request_id=336b711b-c904-4217-8aad-4869fcf0b19d fwd="38.98.150.200" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133 protocol=https
2017-03-28T20:30:25.649733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=boiling-mountain-81402.herokuapp.com request_id=1d7f4c66-557c-4aef-b35f-e87ab60dd9f2 fwd="38.98.150.200" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1754 protocol=https
2017-03-28T20:30:26.959247+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-mountain-81402.herokuapp.com request_id=d444e061-f301-40dd-a7db-63f132e9abe2 fwd="38.98.150.200" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=228 protocol=https
```

Comment: Do you set the `root` path?

Comment: I did. It's set to "sites#index".

Comment: Any error on the heroku log?